# webpack не видит NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, webpack, babel

устанавливаю переменную 
`export NODE_PATH=/home/user/path/to/my/project/libs`
webpack её видит (вывожу в консоли её в конфиге)

В папке libs есть файл Operation.js

```
 export default class Operation {}
```

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Operation'

Может мне по другому задать её?

Comment: Так а зачем NODE_PATH менять, лучше алиасы в webpack используйте.

Comment: да, это решение! не много работал с webpack'ом и не знал о такой возможности. Спасибо большое!